# Build failure for Create React App 2.0 to Zeit

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vercel

I have built an application using the `create-react-app` version 2.0 locally. It runs, builds and works as expected. I am trying to deploy it to Zeit, using `now`. It works fine when I run the `now` command from withing the generated `./build` folder (`npm run build`'s destination).

My goal is to integrate it with GitHub so it updates the deployment on `git push`. Unfortunately, running `now` at the project's root folder doesn't work. I have a `now.json` file with the following contents:

```
{
 "version": 2,
 "name": "somename",
 "builds": [
  {
   "src": "package.json",
   "use": "@now/static-build"
  }
 ],
 "routes": [
  {
   "src": "^/static/(.*)",
   "dest": "/static/$1"
  },
  {
   "src": ".*",
   "dest": "/index.html"
  }
 ]
}
```

and my `package.json` contains the `"now-build": "serve --single ./build"` script.

**The error**

Every build attempt from the root folder results to this error:
[image]

**Tries**

I have tried changing the `now-build` to `now-start` and it didn't work, as it specifically needs `now-build`, I have tried removing the `now.json` altogether and it didn't work and every YouTube video I found on the issue doesn't do anything different but it works for them.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the build command is wrong. The correct one is:
`"now-build": "npm run build && mv build dist"` in the package.json.

More info: https://github.com/zeit/now-examples/tree/master/create-react-app